# python class inheritance from different files

Tags: python

I am learning python and encountered a problem that I don't understand.
I have created a class called Person in a file classes_parent.py

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def printname(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

x = Person('John', 'Doe')
x.printname()
```

I have created a subclass called Student in file classes_child.py:

```
from classes_parent import Person

class Student(Person):
    pass

s = Student('Alex', 'Doe')
s.printname()
```

The problem is that the output when I run classes_child.py is this:

```
John Doe  
Alex Doe
```

Why I get both names and not just the student name, i.e. Alex Doe?

Comment: Because you have `x = Person('John', 'Doe'); x.printname()` in the first file…!?

Comment: Yes, but they are not part of the class in the first file, just using the class Person. What I understood is that the command: ```from classes_parent import Person``` I just import the class Person, not the whole code included in the file. That's what I am trying to understand.

Comment: The entire file gets executed to define everything you can import. Python can't just pick something out of the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why the "if name equals main" boilerplate exists: so you can separate a module's *library* and *main* functionality. Change your files like this:

classes_parent.py

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def printname(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Person('John', 'Doe')
    x.printname()
```

classes_child.py

```
from classes_parent import Person

class Student(Person):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Student('Alex', 'Doe')
    s.printname()
```

Now when you run classes_child.py, it won't run the *main* code from classes_parent.py, and you'll just get `Alex Doe` as output.

For more details see:

- [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/4518341)
- [How do I find the current module name?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-find-the-current-module-name) (Python FAQ)